# Tag Search Only Displays first 50 Matches

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

So I dove down the rabbit hole retagging [google](/questions/tagged/google) + [visualization](/questions/tagged/visualization) to [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization). I noticed that the [google](/questions/tagged/google) wiki says:

> ## Please do not use this tag.
>
> [google](/questions/tagged/google) is a very low quality tag, having very little useful
>   meaning; please be more specific, using tags like:
>
> - [google-search](/questions/tagged/google-search)
> - [google-account](/questions/tagged/google-account)
> - [google-apps](/questions/tagged/google-apps)
> - [google-calendar](/questions/tagged/google-calendar)
> - etc.

So I started looking at what tags had `google-` in them, so I went to the tag page, and typed in `google-`. I only got 50 entries with no options to go to the next page, or change the page size, and got suspicious when the last `google-` tag was [google-calendar](/questions/tagged/google-calendar) with all the other tags being `google-a` `google-b` or `google-c`. A quick search for [google-earth](/questions/tagged/google-earth) shows it exists, and [an API query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=name&inname=google-&filter=!9f8L7EC3I&site=stackoverflow&run=true) tells me there are actually 227 separate tags with the `google-` prefix.

Any chance we could get the tag search fixed to at least show pages so that we don't have to go digging through the API?

Nothing urgent, just would be nice...

Comment: This is an edge case - very few searches have that many results.  I'll take a look at what this would take though, it's a change to several parts of the pipeline

Comment: @Nick, since I can get the info anyway, and it is an edge case, [status-delayed] is fine. It really isn't a huge issue, just one that I caught and needed to write down. You guys do a great job prioritizing, don't let this throw a wrench in the plans.